# Where can I find a jQuery syntax highlighting plugin for Notepad++?

Tags: jquery, syntax, notepad++, highlighting

jQuery has a syntax all its own<sup>*</sup>, and when writing ridiculously lengthy expressions I often yearn for some sort of highlighting. Is there a way to achieve this in Notepad++?

<sup>*<sub>except for the bits that are shared with CSS and JavaScript...</sub></sup>

Comment: @Jonathan - you have completely changed the question with your edit. The OP was asking (though I admit, in a profoundly useless way) about a Notepad++ plugin to highlight jQuery syntax, not for JavaScript syntax-highlighting.

Comment: @Shog9 - thank you so much for that edit... I was trying to think of a way to salvage this question because I didn't even know Notepad++ had intellisense until now and I am actually curious how to find this plugin.

Comment: @John: it does? Huh... I stopped using it years ago, after getting frustrated with the poor keyboard support in the Find dialog.

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ has a langs.xml file in its directory that you can edit to add a jQuery langueage type and the keywords you want highlighted.

You can start by copying and editing the Javascript element:

```
<Language name="javascript" ext="js" commentLine="//" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/">
    <Keywords name="instre1">abstract boolean break byte case catch char class const continue debugger default delete do double else enum export extends final finally float for function goto if implements import in instanceof int interface long native new package private protected public return short static super switch synchronized this throw throws transient try typeof var void volatile while with true false prototype</Keywords>
</Language>
```