# Notepad++ jQuery Syntax-Highlighting

Tags: jquery, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I am looking for a jQuery syntax highlighting plugin for Notepad++, or at least some XML that I can put in the lang.xml file so my jQuery is more readable.

There is a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274947/where-can-i-find-a-jquery-syntax-highlighting-plugin-for-notepad) but it was closed and not properly answered. It's also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713889/what-is-your-favourite-javascript-jquery-code-editor), but again without a definitive answer.

I know that Notepad++ is not ideal for developing AJAX apps and what-not, but I am happy with it for my use.

Comment: Why can't you use JavaScript highlighting mode?

Comment: The question without a definitive answer should have been the one closed, precisely because it *cannot* have a definitive answer... the first one could simply use a better title.

Comment: It's not syntax highlighting (as VisioN said, what's wrong with the JS highlighting?) but I wrote a [jQuery code hinting plugin](http://www.jamesallardice.com/2011/11/26/jquery-code-hinting-in-notepad/) for Notepad++ a while back which may help out a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Notepad++ a lot, there is no specific plugin for jquery that I know of.

Taken from jQuery website

> jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML
>   document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions
>   for rapid web development. jQuery is designed to change the way that
>   you write JavaScript.

The JavaScript mode should work for you, I know it works for me. Syntax is the same since it's just a library.

Answer (score 2):

This guy made an add-on for writing JQuery in notepad++ and I think it will help:
https://github.com/jamesallardice/notepadplus-jQuery

Comment: "This guy" is me and I already posted a link to that plugin in the comments on the question!

Comment: Nice to meet you. When I posted it you hadn't commented yet but after you did I edited my answer. Excuse me if I offended you in any way.

Comment: No worries, you didn't offend me! I was just pointing out that the link had already been posted (the comment was posted 15 minutes ago, your answer was posted 11 minutes ago).

Comment: This link is no longer valid, can someone point me to the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I developed highlighting "langs.xml" for php, javascript and jquery.
Download: [langs.xml](https://hotfile.com/dl/199054466/f10b17c/langs.xml.html)

"langs.xml" file is in here for windows: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\langs.xml

I want to say one more thing different. My Dreamweaver theme (Users who use Dreamweaver after use Notepad++). Download [Dreamweaver.xml](https://hotfile.com/dl/199056455/b4d5264/Dreamweaver.xml.html)

"Dreamweaver.xml" file is in here for windows: C:\Program Files\Notepad++\themes\Dreamweaver.xml